# FindDevices and DeviceOpen cannot find SenseHAT

Tags: raspberry-pi, input-devices

I have a Raspberry-Pi 3 with a Sense Hat connected.  The Python 3 application can find, query, and write to the Sense Hat. However, in Mathematica `FindDevices[]` does not find it and `DeviceOpen["SenseHAT"]` shows a couple of errors about pins before it says that a Sense Hat could not be found.

How do get Mathematica on the Raspberry Pi to see the Sense Hat?

The Sense Hat works because the Python 3 app can see it. Therefore, I think it is a Mathematica issue.

*Note that online Wolfram Language reference link for Sense Hat is broken (only has Japanese and, I think, Mandarin) but the installed PC desktop (not Rasberry Pi desktop) documentation does have it in English.*

Comment: I think you should "join" the following discussion, to make things move faster... http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/786114

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I bought a RPI 3 Model B with a SenseHat a few months ago.
Unfortunately none of the proposed solutions I found helped.

However upgrading to Mathematica 11.2, which was released about two weeks ago, solved it for me.

Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade wolfram-engine`, then open Mathematica and run `DeviceOpen["SenseHAT"]`.

After that Mathematica told me to reboot and run two commands in the terminal (which I unfortunately don't remember but they are given).
I know it's roughly a year too late, but I hope this still helps.

Comment: It's absolutly not too late. Here, on Mathematica Stack Exchange, we cumulate knowledge over years. Too many people thinks that Question/Anwers are short lived. In your case the only problem to have upvotes is that most peole can't verify your answer.